# Estimating the effect of inductors in an RL circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

I'm trying to understand how an inductor works in an RL circuit. When I use an air core inductor, my estimation is fairly accurate to the test circuit but as soon as I use an inductor with a core, the calculations don't match the real circuit. Here are both examples values

V = 24V AC and f = 50Hz for both examples.

Example 1 - air core inductor
R = 17 ohms (coil's resistance) and L = 20mH
Calculations for XL, Z, I, etc match the measured values. No problem here.

Example 2 - 20mH inductor with core (https://au.rs-online.com/mobile/p/leaded-inductors/1633404/)
R = 20 ohms (external resistance added because coil didn't seem to have much DC resistance) L = 20mH
Calculations don't match the measurements at all. Infact, the inductor behaves as if it's not even in the circuit. Hardly any voltage drop across it and the circuit current seems to be controlled by the resistor.

I know there is something here that I don't understand, can anyone please help me identify what I'm missing and explain it? Why are the calculations not working as expected in the second example.

Thanks

Comment: Your "inductor with core" is a transformer. What did you connect to the unused coil when you did your test?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @the Photon, I believe the component I used is a common mode choke, not a transformer. I didn't connect the other side of the inductor to anything, just used one coil.

Comment: A common mode choke is one way to use a transformer. But your result is more consistent with having shorted the unused coil than with leaving it open. Do you have a photo showing how you hooked everything up?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't a photo but I'm sure I left the other two legs open. Hopefully this might help - I tried to test this problem with a contactor coil, pulled it apart and used it as air core and it worked as expected. Then I took the cores out and put them in the coil, which increased the inductance and the calculations didn't match after that. In this experiment there was only one coil.

Comment: Whatever went wrong, I don't think you've shared it yet. What is the source of the 24 VAC? What instrument did you use to measure the voltage across the coil? How did you make the connections (did you use a breadboard, veroboard, solder-tacking, ...)? Etc. I don't know your experience level, but if you're really a beginner then we need to know things like, do you know which sockets in a breadboard are connected (if you used a breadboard)? Did you use the right input sockets of your multimeter? Etc. A lot of this might be answered if you could take a photo of your setup and share it.

Comment: I understand @the Photon. My understanding of electrical/electronics is intermediate. Here are the requested details. 24vac output from a variac, not using breadboard, all direct connections, using multimeter for resistance and voltage measurement, panel meter for current, power and power factor measurement, LCR tester to measure inductance. I believe that all my connections are correct because it works with air core. Please feel free to ask more clarification if they help you understand my situation better or if I have missed anything. Thanks